# Convert Num to Doublle in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function that calculates the average of the values of a list containing type Num.

Here is what I tried:

```
mean :: Num a => [a] -> Double
mean [] = error "Trying to calculate mean of 0 values"
mean x = sumx / lengthx
  where
    sumx = fromIntegral (sum x)
    lengthx = fromIntegral length x
```

GHCI rejects the fromIntegral function because it expects an Integral type not a Num.

Is there a way to convert a Num, whatever its specific type, to a Double?

Comment: `fromIntegral` turns an `Integral` type into a user-requested `Num` type. You want something that can turn an arbitrary `Num` into a `Fractional` value (which `(/)` can accept as an argument).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with converting `Num a => a` to a `Double` is that a `Num` may not actually be a number at all. There is no requirement for a member of the `Num` class to be a number of some sort. You can go and implement an instance of `Num` for anything, even for unit.

One obvious real-life example is `Complex`: it has an instance of `Num`, but a complex number can't always be converted to a real one.

If you want your function to work with integers, just specify `Integral` as your constraint.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I finally found the way to do this:

```
mean :: Fractional a => [a] -> a
mean xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)
```

This works even if I apply it to a list of Integers.  I am not sure why because Fractional does not apply to Integers according to the documentation I have read.

My understanding of Haskell is still obviously quite limited.

Comment: This doesn't work for integers, try `mean [1, 2, 3 :: Int]`.

Comment: When you write `mean [1,2,3]`, the literal `[1,2,3]` is not a list of integers. (In koan form: a list of integers is not a list of integers when it's `mean`.)

Comment: Thanks Noughtmare and Daniel.  I only figured that out after my post.

Answer (score 0):

A more general way to write it is to use `Real`:

```hs
mean :: (Real a, Fractional b) => [a] -> b
mean xs = realToFrac (sum xs) / fromIntegral (length xs)
```

But that is not completely satisfactory because this doesn't work on lists of `Complex` numbers or other non-`Real` numbers.